# Print the Process Tree of Kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am newbie to C and Kernel modules. I am trying to print all the kernel processes and their children printed. However when I insert my module terminal it gives only part of processes. My algorithm is first getting to the root of process tree, then getting children recursively step by step.

my code is below:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <asm/current.h>
#include <linux/list.h>


void getProcInfo(struct task_struct* task);

static int mod_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "ProcInfo sucessfully loaded.\n");
    struct task_struct *task=current;


    while(task->pid != 1 ){
        task=task->parent;
    }
    //task = current->real_parent;
    getProcInfo(task);
    return 0; 
}

static void mod_exit(void)
{
        printk(KERN_ALERT "ProcInfo sucessfully unloaded.\n");
}

void getProcInfo(struct task_struct* task)
{
    struct list_head *children_tasks;
    children_tasks = &(task->children);

    list_for_each(children_tasks, &(task->children))
    {

        struct task_struct *child_task;
        child_task = list_entry(children_tasks, struct task_struct, sibling);

        printk(KERN_INFO "The parent process is \"%s\" (pid %i)\tThe process is \"%s\" (pid %i)\n",
        child_task->parent->comm, child_task->parent->pid,child_task->comm, child_task->pid);
        getProcInfo(child_task);
    }
}

module_init(mod_init);
module_exit(mod_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Nihad");
```

Comment: 'struct task_struct *task=current;' - references external data not listed in your question:(

Comment: Review your use of the `list_entry` macro.  You're passing it `struct list_head **` where I believe it expects `struct list_head *`.  It's possibly also worth double-checking whether the task's child list is protected by any of the kernel's concurrent-access mechanisms (e.g. RCU).  You can probably find example code walking the task child list in kernel/sched.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit: `current` is a "global" (actually per-cpu) pointer which points to a task currently executing on CPU where we're running `mod_init`. It would be likely be `insmod` process

Comment: The last parameter of your `list_entry` macro call is incorrect. It should be `children` (not `sibling`) because `children_tasks` is iterating over the `children` list.